# Write a falling power method

Tags: java

```
public static long fallingPower(int n, int k)
```

However, in the related operation of falling power that is useful in many combinatorial formulas and denoted syntactically by underlining the exponent, each term that gets multiplied into the product is always one less than the previous term. For example, the falling power 83 would be computed as 8 * 7 * 6 = 336. Similarly, the falling power 105 would equal 10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 = 30240. Nothing important changes if the base n is negative. For example, the falling power (-4)5 is computed the exact same way as -4 * -5 * -6 * -7 * -8  = -6720.

This method should compute and return the falling power nk where n can be any integer, and k can be any nonnegative integer. (Analogous to ordinary powers, n0 = 1 for any n.) The automated tester is designed so that your method does not need to worry about potential integer overflow as long as you perform computations using long type of 64-bit integers.

```
public static long fallingPower(int n, int k)
    long result = n;

    for (int i = n; i < k; i--) {
      result = result * n;
    }

    return result;
  }
```

Is my method right?

Comment: You want to make sure you increment I or make sure that i > k. I realize the comment above says the same thing

Comment: This "falling power method" is actually called a Permutation by the way.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n

Comment: You also might want to verify your arguments.  k normally must be equal to or greater than one, and no more than n.  n is usually required to be positive (greater than 0).

Comment: public static long fallingPower(int n, int k)
    long result = n;
    if (k <0);
    for (int i = n; i > k; i++) {
      result = result * n;
    }

    return result;
  }

Comment: Please don't post code in comments; the formatting makes it unreadable.  Edit your question and add the code, properly formatted, in the question.

Comment: Please explain your thinking behind `for (int i = n; i < k; i--)`. Only with that information an answer can really explain the problem. It would also reduce the impression that you copy a homework assignment and add some random code fragment to make people do your work.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to multiply `k` times, starting with `n` and decrementing each factor by one. Your code currently doesn't really make any sense. I would do it like this:

```
public static long fallingPower(int n, int k)
    long result = n;

    for (int i = 1; i < k; i++) {
      result = result * (n-i);
    }

    return result;
}
```

`k` is required to be non-negative, so you need to handle that in the method too, for example with an exception:

```
public static long fallingPower(int n, int k)
    if(k < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative exponent");
    }
    long result = n;

    for (int i = 1; i < k; i++) {
      result = result * (n-i);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
public static long fallingPower(int n, int k){
long result = n;

for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
 n=n-1;
 result = result * n;
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: Please use your commenting privilege instead of mixing comments into your answer.

Comment: It would. It would never enter the for loop and return `n`.

Comment: But it should return n*n-1 for k=1 according to requirement, right?

Comment: No. That's `k = 2`. `k` is the number of factors (thus called the exponent).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static long fallingPower(int n, uint k){
    long result = 1;

    for(; k > 0; k--, n--){
        result *= n;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of the programming logic, not your method, if I am not wrong. I do not have error handling. I started going backward just like you, assuming the least integer permutation of zero is equal to 1 and at least we need to return 1.
You can start from k number before the n and multiply thereafter until you reach n.

```
public static long fallingPower(int n, int k) 
{
    long result = 1;
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= k ; i++) {
      result = result * n;
      n = n-1;
    }
    return result;
}
```